gated deep cross implementation
I'm trying to search around for the implementation Gated deep cross network: https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.04635, an updated version for DCN but seems like it's not yet supported.
I'm trying to tweak the Cross layer implementation by adding gate layers with sigmoid activation:
      self._gate_u = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
          self._projection_dim,
          kernel_initializer=_clone_initializer(self._kernel_initializer),
          kernel_regularizer=self._kernel_regularizer,
          use_bias=False,
          dtype=self.dtype,
      )
      self._gate_v = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
          last_dim,
          kernel_initializer=_clone_initializer(self._kernel_initializer),
          bias_initializer=self._bias_initializer,
          kernel_regularizer=self._kernel_regularizer,
          bias_regularizer=self._bias_regularizer,
          use_bias=self._use_bias,
          dtype=self.dtype,
          activation="sigmoid",
      )
    ....
def call:
    return x0 * prod_output + self._gate_v(self._gate_u(x)) + x

But loss doesn't converge for my use case. Is the implementation correct?

GDCN? Please add more context.

It's gated deep cross network, from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.04635
